# Random & Instant Timeout Expired Error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

**Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.**

We are using C#.net MVC3 and Sql Server 2008.

I have this weird problem with my App. This error appears instantly (there is not waiting time after launching the new action) and randomly (each time the app saves data in the database).

An example of an action is: Clicking a next button, the app should save data in database but, the error appears with no waiting time.

Besides, when the error appears you can refresh the page and you can proceed without problem.

We have tested the app incrementing the TimeOut on our webconfig, but it was useless.

Do you know why this error happen? If you need more information just tell me.

I will be waiting, thanks

Comment: Please post the code that is specific to this error being thrown.  We can't help without it.

Comment: Are you leaving some connection unclosed? Are you performing a transaction that is not committed?

Comment: which orm? More datails.